# Should I use a multi-transitive association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I think I may need a multi-transitive association in my rails application. I need some help making this decision and with the implementation logic.

I have 4 models.

```
1. User - has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
2. Locations - has_and_belongs_to_many :users
3. Customer - model in question
4. Job - model in question
```

Each user is assigned to certain locations so that the user can view customers and edit jobs for the locations that they are associated with.

The part where I think I need the multi-transitive association is with my `Customer` and `Job` models.

Essentially, there should be a single customer record. The customer should have many jobs at many locations. However, a user should only see customers at locations they are associated with. This is the part that has me stuck.

UPDATE

Just trying to come up with an idea, maybe this association would work:

```
User has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
Location has_and_belongs_to_many :users
Customer has_and_belongs_to_many :locations, has_many :jobs
Job belongs_to :customers, belongs_to :locations
```

Then I could access all customers for a given location via

```
User has_many :customers, through: :locations
User has_many :jobs, through: :locations
```

Comment: Seems like you want `Customer has_many :jobs` (unless multiple customers can have the same job) and `Job belongs_to :location`

Comment: @Stefan So when I load the customer database for a given user I would essentially load 'customers = current_user.locations.jobs.customers'. This just seems inefficient to me. If I were to create some association with direct reference to the customer model through the locations model would that work better? Multiple customers cannot have the same job.

Comment: The description of how the 4 models are related is incomplete. For example, what's the relationship between job and location? Is a given job only at one location? Or can a job be split across multiple locations?

Comment: Trying my best to explain. A user should be able to login and see all of their locations that they do work. They should be able to select a location and see all of the customers for that location and also see all of the jobs for that location (a location could be like a region or city). Its possible that a user may work under the US location and also the Canada location so if that user selects Canada, then the user should only be able to view (via association) the Canada customers and the Canada jobs. @lurker

Comment: `belongs_to` defines a singular relationship. So `belongs_to :customer` not `:customers`.

Comment: You also want `Location` `has_many :jobs`

Comment: Your idea is fine but a partial solution. It doesn't get you to `user.customers`. The answer @PrinceBansal gave is complete outside of perhaps adding the customer/location relationship which was missing from your problem description. Why not accept the posted answer? Anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Trying my best to explain. A user should be able to login and see all of their locations that they do work. They should be able to select a location and see all of the customers for that location and also see all of the jobs for that location (a location could be like a region or city). Its possible that a user may work under the US location and also the Canada location so if that user selects Canada, then the user should only be able to view (via association) the Canada customers and the Canada jobs

Below code may solve your problem.

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many_and_belongs_to :locations
      has_many :customers, through: :locations
      has_many :jobs, through: :locations
    end

    class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many_and_belongs_to :users
      has_many_and_belongs_to :customers
      has_many_and_belongs_to :jobs
    end

    class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_and_belongs_to_many :locations, 
    end

    class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many_and_belongs_to :locations
    end
```

In controller now you can use:

say params = `{region: 'canada'}`

```
@canada_jobs = current_user.jobs.where(locations: {region: params[:region]})
@canada_customers = current_user.customers.where(locations: {region: params[:region]})
```

Comment: This is looking pretty close to what I need. I do have one question, with the association for Location and Job, in order to view a customer for a location a Job would have to exist?

Comment: @CannonMoyer it's not obvious from your problem statement that a customer has any relationship with a location other than through a job.  You can have `Customer` `has_and_belongs_to_many :locations` (and vice versa) if that's what your database supports.

Comment: I would assume a `Job` `belongs_to :customer` and `Customer` `has_many :jobs`. But, that doesn't affect the net intent of the answer. It's just another assumption to fill in the gaps on the model descriptions.